# Repeater Control in Asp.Net?

Tags: asp.net, repeater, findcontrol

In web application using asp.net, i am using repeater control, in `ItmeCommand` event i am trying to find a control using fid control method, i write the code for finding the control it is working fine, when the control is not in repeater control, i am getting exception. How can i handle the exception if the control is not in repeater control. My code is like this :

```
if (((DropDownList)rpPendingApprovals.Items[i].FindControl "drpBack")).SelectedItem.Value != "0")
```

when dropdown controls is not there, in repeater then how can i handle this exception help me, thank  you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you've tried Shoaib's code you are getting exception because if the drodown is not null the second expression is checked which if SelectedItem is null creates the exception so nest the expressions as

```
var dropdown = (DropDownList)rpPendingApprovals.Items[i].FindControl("drpBack"));

if (dropdown != null && dropdown.SelectedItem != null)
   if(dropdown.SelectedValue !="0")
```

problem hopefully is gone

Answer (score 3):

why don't you do this?

```
var dropdown = (DropDownList)rpPendingApprovals.Items[i].FindControl("drpBack"));

    if (dropdown != null && dropdown.SelectedItem.Value != "0")
```

Comment: i am getting exception Shoaib

Comment: can you show me more code... how you are iterating the items?

Answer (score 2):

```
DropDownList drpBack = (DropDownList)rpPendingApprovals.Items[i].FindControl("drpBack");

if(drpBack!=null)
{
  if(drpBack.SelectedItem.Value != "0")
    {
       // Do Whatever you want
    }
}
```

Comment: Pankaj, i am getting object reference not set to instance of an object , thank you for reply

Comment: I am getting the exception at if(drpBack.SelectedItem.Value != "0"), pankaj

Comment: when data is not binding to dropdown list i am visibling false, if data is there i am visibling true, when no data is there in dropdown then it is giving error

Comment: @Suryasasidhar: For this u need to change ur approach like   if(drpBack.Items.Count == 0)
    {
       drpBack.Visible=false;
    } else {        drpBack.Visible=true; }

Comment: Let me know, if you have any concern.